# Access data of a parent component from a child component in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch-2

I am writing a Sencha Touch 2 app. I have recently got stuck with the following problem.

I have a Container view which has data bound to it with setRecord(myRecord). So my question is what's the right way to populate my subcomponents with this data?

Here is my code(simplified for brevity):

```js
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Item', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  config: {
    fields: ['name', 'description', 'image'],
    proxy: { /* proxy config */ }
  }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.DetailsView', {
  extend: 'Ext.Container',
  xtype: 'itemdetails',

  config: {
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
      {
        xtype: 'container',
        flex: 1,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
          {
            xtype: 'img',
            src: '' // SHOULD BE POPULATED FROM DATA.image
          },
          {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Buy',
            action: 'buyItem'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        flex: 3,
        tpl: '<h1>{name}</h1><p>{description}</p>' // SHOULD BE POPULATED FROM DATA
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

And here is the code that populates and shows my view from a controller:

```js
Ext.define('Myapp.controller.Main', {
    ...
    refs: {
      itemDetails: {
        selector: '',
        xtype: 'itemdetails',
        autoCreate: true
      }
    }
    routes: {
      'item/details/:id': 'showItemDetails'
    },
    ...

    showItemDetails: function(id) {
      MyApp.model.Item.load(id, {
        callback: function(item){
          var card = this.getItemDetails();
          card.setRecord(item);
          this._showCard(card);
        },
        scope: this
      });
    }
});
```

I first implemented it with a simple Container containing a 'tpl', but in this case I was not able to have a button inside it, which would be queryable from the controller. Any ideas?

Thx, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a comment in the Sencha Touch docs for [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component), add a setRecords function that recursively sets the record on each item in the items component hierarchy:

```
setRecords: function(component, record) {
    me = this;
    component.getItems().each(function(item) {
        if (typeof item.setRecord == 'function') {
            item.setRecord(record);
        }

        //set record on all subitems
        if (typeof item.getItems == 'function') {
            var subItems = item.getItems();
            if (subItems.getCount() > 0) {
                me.setRecords(item, record);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and then override setRecord to call the new function:

```
setRecord: function(record) {
    result = this.callParent([record]);
    this.setRecords(this, record);
    return result;
}
```

So now no more need to explicitly set the data on specific components